# WP8: RichTextBox has no Document property

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, richtextbox

So I have a RichTextBox on my xaml page in my WP8 project, set up like this:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="ContentDisplay" IsReadOnly="True">

</RichTextBox>
```

I'm trying to get it to display some text. Every single piece of code I find on the net references Document property. However, when I try to do anything with it, it just isn't there. There's no

```
var test = ContentDisplay.Document;
```

to set to.

When I try to compile the project with aforementioned line, I get a following error:

```
'System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox' does not contain a definition for 'Document'
and no extension method 'Document' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox' could be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Trying to google it, i find references to a similar but-not-the-same problem, this time with people trying to use 'Text' property (which, unlike Document property, doesn't even exist)
So, please tell, how can I use that control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add content to this control using `Blocks` and `Paragraphs`. The following will add another line to the `RichTextBlox`.

```cs
var paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.Inlines.Add("Hello");
richText.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```

```xml
<RichTextBox x:Name="richText">
  <Paragraph>
    <Run Text="Line one" />
  </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

The Document property is available on the Silverlight version of the control. Unfortunately, not all features were ported to windows phone.

Comment: There's no 'Blocks' property either, at least not in WinForms.