# Making clickable URLs in RichTextBox using bindings

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

My XAML has a `DataTemplate` defined which has `ItemsSource` set to some data class, which holds properties that will be presented in UI. One property is "Files", which has to display one or more files in the form of `<Hyperlink NavigateUri="URLtoFILE">Filename</Hyperlink> (optional filesize)`.

The property is currently of type `string` where I'm concatenating different files' URLs and text together. But the stuff I put into that property display on screen verbatim.

I've seen this: [WP8: RichTextBox has no Document property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564772/wp8-richtextbox-has-no-document-property), but I have the problem of using data templates and bindings, which makes referencing the `RichTextBox` object in code impossible (is it?).

How can I mix text and clickable URLs within a WP8 control that is using data templates and bindings?

EDIT: If it helps, the `ItemsSource` always holds only one object.

EDIT: Part of XAML

```
<Grid>
    <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="List">
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True">
                    </RichTextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show a list of urls?
If you want this :

```
<lisbox itemSource={Binding YourItemSource} selectedItem="{Binding ItemProperty}">
 <listbox.ItemTemplate>
  <dataTemplate>
   <textblock>
    <Hyperlink Command="{Binding HyperLinkTapped}" NavigateUri="URLtoFILE"></Hyperlink>
   </textblock><
  </datatemplate>
 </listbox.itemtemplate>
</listbox>
```

Comment: I put this inside my current data template?

Comment: If you replace 
<RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True">
</RichTextBox>
to 
<textblock>
<Hyperlink Command="{Binding HyperLinkTapped}" NavigateUri="URLtoFILE"></Hyperlink>
   </textblock>
It's work?

Comment: Well, the problem is that `URLtoFILE` is dynamic, and I will only know the URL in-code (from a webservice).

Comment: What type is your itemSource?Model?
And for binding:
'private Uri _uriFile;
public Uri UriFile{
get { return _uriFile; }
          set
          {
              name = _uriFile;
              OnPropertyChanged("UriFile");
          }'
NavigateUri="{Binding UriFile,mode=twoway"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37261/discussion-between-matdevwp8-and-howie)